# print keyword for C# ...why not?

Tags: c#

My reasons for the idea/proposal are following:

1) Console.WriteXX() is  possibly  used  more often than many  keywords in C#
2) The Console as an I/O device  is not going away anytime soon.
3) I cannot  think of any general purpose programming language which doesn't provide the "write to console" facility in one form or another.
4) aesthetics (i.e. clean, simple, short , direct )
5) print "Hello" ; doesn't make me think that I am typing more than whats needed. Every time I have to write Console.WritXX() ... or even read it in code , its a chore.
6) Its closer to the C/C++ family values and tradition of providing special status to the basic text based  I/O
7) Its hard to conceive of a future scenario when the decision to make "print" a keyword will be regretted.
8) print as in { print "hello"; } instead of print as in { print("hello");} is unlikely to break any existing code.

Comment: Wouldn't really consider it a chore to write. If you use the snippet all you have to type is cw+TAB.

Comment: Why on earth pick this C# verbosity problem out of all the others?

Comment: There is a good reason that Console class is in the core  system namespace. Other forms of I/O (Web,Winforms,File I/O etc) will likely evolve and change form over time. But as long as humans use text based communication, a general purpose programming language can safely provide a keyword for text based Console I/O. There is also a reason that a great many of other main general purpose languages (python, perl, etc) have specific keywords rather than library calls for this most fundamental of I/Os.  Have a look at http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Hello,_world!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because C# <strike>isn't only</strike> is generally not used in a console. Wether it's ASP.NET, WinForms or WPF, there are many uses for the langage where "printing" does not make any sense.

Comment: "Because C# isn't only used in a console. " .. same goes for any general purpose programming language.

Comment: Not really. Python, Ruby, C, C++, Haskell... they don't have native (as in "installed by default") GUI packages. They use a console as their primary mean of communication with a user. However, the presence of native event handling facilities within C# seems to indicate that the language was actually intended to be used in a GUI (in line with Microsoft's previous product, VB6, which couldn't even use a console). A console is almost a second-class citizen within .NET...

Comment: Rephrase then:  C# is usually used in a GUI environment, where "print" has no use.  Perl, PHP, Python...they have a reason to "print".  C# doesn't -- it already has the ability, it's just not as pretty as you'd like.

Comment: Conceptually "print" is not a keyword. Further, look at Python 3: they decided to make "print" a function. Mistakes happen.

Answer (score 4):

In C# we have a lot of ways to output the data. It's very confusing if you change `Console.Write` to print, because programmers may ask "print to what? to the screen? to the printer?". While using `Console.Write` is quite clear, we know it's writing data to the `Console`. And also `FileStream.Write` make us know that it's writing to a file. A `MemoryStream.Write` is writing to the memory... It's so nice, isn't it? So why do we need a confusing `print`?

Comment: totally agree.  Plus WinForm applications don't even have a console to write to!  You need to explicitly instantiate one if you want one.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create an [alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664765%28VS.71%29.aspx) for System.out.WriteLine() to save your wrist?

```
using c = System.Console;

c.WriteLine("Hello World");
```

Or use a code snippet in your IDE?

Console.WriteLine is a .NET Framework method, so all .NET languages use it consistently.  Why add additional keywords to c# which is only one of many .NET languages?

Comment: Because that will make your code harder to read and maintain.

Comment: LOL for 'System.out.WriteLine', you must be a Java programmer.

Comment: how so? the compiler's smart enough you don't need to explicitly reference the namespace and its only an issue if you expect there to be method collisions.

Comment: @Danny Chen - LOL for your comment, you must be a tool.

Answer (score 0):

Print is too generic to describe what is really going on, and it only really applies to the console itself. There are several different methods for outputting information to various interfaces, and WriteXX (as you put it) is more descriptive of what is actually occurring. You're not printing anything, you're writing it to the interface. C# was made to be more descriptive of what is going on, not to latch onto holdovers of other languages.